# Leetcode Problem Runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'struct value_type' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, vector, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

Original Leetcode Problem: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/94/trees/628/

When I change line 23 to `while (result.size() < t.second+1)` it works fine, but it doesn't work when I have `while (result.size()-1 < t.second)`. Aren't these equivalent expressions? Why am I getting this error?

`Line 922: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'struct value_type' (stl_vector.h)`

My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        if (root == NULL)
            return result;
        queue<pair<TreeNode*, int>> q;
        q.push(make_pair(root, 0));
        while (!q.empty())
        {
            pair<TreeNode*,int> t = q.front();
            q.pop();

            while (result.size()-1 < t.second)
                result.push_back({});
            result[t.second].push_back(t.first->val);

            if (t.first->left != NULL)
                q.push(make_pair(t.first->left, t.second+1));
            if (t.first->right != NULL)
                q.push(make_pair(t.first->right, t.second+1));

        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: They're not equivalent. `result.size()` is unsigned, so if it is `0`, then `result.size()-1` isn't `-1`, but instead it rolls over to a huge value, usually something in the range of billions of billions.

Comment: Ah I didn't know it was unsigned! That makes sense! Thank you.